# Using loop foreach in xml expression

Tags: c#, xml, loops

help me in such problem!  I need to create xml file. Elements for my xml file i isolate from text file ( config screenos juniper). I want take the key words , which will be as nodes and its elements.

I want to achieve such output (xml file):

```
<VR1>

   <...>

</VR1>
<VR2>

   <...>

</VR2>
<VR3>

   <...>

</VR3>
```

But I have only such output:

```
    <VR3>

       <...>

   </VR3>
```

**Such code:**

```
                foreach (var match in myCollection)
            {

                StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();

                XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
                xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(match);
                ;
                             ...
                             ...

                xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
                xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
                docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
                //write the path where you want to save the Xml file
                docSave.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() +"Roting.xml");
            }
```

Here myCollection contains : VR1,VR2,VR3.
It seems obvious that I'm wrong to use loop *foreach* , but I can not understand how to use it correctly in this context.

Comment: you are overwriting your doc

Comment: agree! everything turned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();

            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
            xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();           

        foreach (var match in myCollection)
        {


            xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement(match);
            ;
                         ...
                         ...

            xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();

        }
            xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            XmlDocument docSave = new XmlDocument();
            docSave.LoadXml(stringwriter.ToString());
            //write the path where you want to save the Xml file
            docSave.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString() +"Roting.xml");
```